# DialogFlow unable to Update Draft

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I just tried to update my draft on from the dialog flow site (formerly API.AI), and when I click on "Update Draft", I am getting an error message

"Request contains an invalid argument.
The query pattern 'call $SchemaOrg_Person:given-name' contains an undefined parameter 'given-name'"

This just started showing up today, and I am not sure what it is referencing.  How can I clear this error message and update my draft?

Answer (score 0):

So I am not sure how, but a "parameter" was added to one of my intents for "given-name". As I am not using that parameter, I just deleted it.  Curious as to how it was added though.

Comment: Did you upload the agent from a export agent ZIP?  If so, where did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when there was a dot after the parameter in one of my utterance.

Just delete the dot after the parameter placeholder in the utterance `call @Person:given-name` if it presents.

I hope it helps.